# How to deserialize a String to a Date with Morphia

Tags: java, json, mongodb, deserialization, morphia

I have a Mongo collection with objects of this format:

```
{
    id: 1,
    date: "2020-08-06T12:00:00Z",
    ...
}
```

I have Java code that needs to read from this collection but never writes to it. The process that writes to this collection is not owned by me so I can't necessarily change the format of that date string. I initially tried to model my Java Morphia object like this:

```
@Entity public class MyDocument {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private Date date; 
    ...
}
```

This did not work because Morphia didn't know how to deserialize that date format into a Date object. The solution that I came up with was treating the date as a String on the POJO and then having a getDate() method that did the actual deserialization. I am wondering, is there a better way for me to do this? I know if you're using Jackson you can annotate certain fields with `@JsonDeserialize` and pass a deserializer so I was wondering if there was something similar for Morphia.

My solution (which feels suboptimal to me):

```
@Entity public class MyDocument {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String date; 
    ...

    private Date getDate() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
        try {
            return dateFormat.parse(date);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go ahead and create a simple converter extending the `TypeConverter` like so:

```
public class DateConverter extends TypeConverter {

    private static final String FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";

    private final SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat;

    public DateConverter() {
        super(Date.class);
        this.simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT);
    }

    @Override
    public Object decode(Class<?> targetClass, Object fromDBObject, MappedField optionalExtraInfo) {
        try {
            return simpleDateFormat.parse(((String) fromDBObject));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

The go ahead and register your formatter for your document entity like so:

```
@Entity("Documents")
@Converters(DateConverter.class)
public class Document {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    public Integer getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }

    private Date date;
    public Date getDate() { return date; }
    public void setDate(Date date) { this.date = date; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return "Document{" +
        "id=" + id +
        ", date=" + date +
        '}';
    }

}
```

This will effectively tell Morphia to decode the database incoming values via parsing the string with the desired pattern, resulting directly into a concrete `Date` object without any additional conversion logic.